# Is AFQT geared towards estimating crystallized intelligence?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, measurement, test, iq

In a few papers I have read claims that AFQT is geared largely (mostly?) towards measuring crystallized intelligence.

However, https://study.com/academy/popular/difference-between-the-asvab-afqt.html lists Arithmetic Reasoning, Word Knowledge, Paragraph Comprehension, Mathematics Knowledge as AFQT subtests. That does not seem geared towards mostly / largely crystallized intelligence?

Can you explain what AFQT is *actually* designed to measure?